# Array type is not assignable to parameter of type MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Passed state from Parent to child and managed state in the child component. Worked if I set
`any` but not with `Iform`

**Error details:** Argument of type 'IRemark[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>'.ts(2345)

Parent.tsx

```
export IDetails {
   id?: string
    text: string
}

export interface IMasterForm {
   details?: IDetails[]
}

const InitialState: IMasterForm = {
    details: [
        {id: "1234567879", text:"hello world"}
    ]
} 

const Page = () => {
const [details, setDetails] = useState(InitialState.details)

 const wrapper= useCallback(
    (val: any) => {
        setsDetails(val);
    },
    [setDetails]
  );

retrun(
  <Details_Form wrapper={wrapper} details={details}/>
)
```

this is diffrent project which will be integrated to the parent project

Details_Form.tsx

```
export IChildDetails {
   id?: string
    text: string
}

export interface IChildForm  {
    details?: IChildDetails []
    wrapper: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>
}
 //const compOne = ({ wrapper, details} : any) => { //working
 const compOne = ({ wrapper, details} : IChildForm ) => {

  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(details);

  useEffect(() => {
    wrapper(childState);  //<----- error type undefined not assignable to mosue event html ele 
  }, [wrapper, childState]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different types for the function in the parent and the child.

In the parent, the type is `(val: any) => void` and in the child it's `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>`. Obviously, the `MouseEventHandler` is going to expect a `MouseEvent` as the argument. And you are passing `childState` to it, which id of type `IChildDetails[]`. You should change `wrapper: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>` to `wrapper: (val: any) => void` in the `IChildForm` interface. `wrapper: (val: IChildForm[]) => void` should also work.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152784/stop-re-rendering-using-callback-hooks-in-react