# Stop re-rendering using callback functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I stop Component B to render when I am doing changes in Component A only.

Example: Console.log("A") belongs to Component A while console.log("B") belongs to Component B. Now when I am updating a text in Component, I believe Component A is only called, hence printing A on the console.

However this is not the behavior. In my case both components are invoked, hence both consoles are logged.

**What I want:** Only the calling component should be invoked for an update...

A.tsx

```
retrun(
  <Details_A setter={setter} dataold={dataold}/>
  <Details_B setterOne={setterOne} datanew={datanew}/>
)
```

this is different project which will be integrated to the parent project

Details_A.tsx

```
  console.log("A");
  return (
    <>
      hello world. I am in A now
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: React components rerender for a few reasons. Can you edit your post to include complete [mcve] so we've more context what/where/how/why these components are being triggered to rerender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all children will be re-rendered when we update the state in the parent, there are a few ways to prevent this:

1. If possible you can just move states updates to children directly, that way the parent will not be re-rendered and affect all children
2. You can wrap children in [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) function (which will prevent the re-render of a child if props are not changed), or use `PureComponent`, or base component with the custom `shouldComponentUpdate`

`memo` example:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
...
export const Details_A = memo(({ wrapper, details }) => {
  ...
  return <Something />
})
```